# Word learning of UITextChecker, Swift -- not Working

Tags: swift, xcode

I want my code to add custom words like 'nooooober' into my iphone dictionary. I write below code. But Still UItextField auto-fill is not showing me 'nooooober' word in autofill options.

Here is my code, written in DidFinishlaunching of appdelegate

```
if (UITextChecker.hasLearnedWord("nooooober")){
        UITextChecker.learnWord("nooooober")
}
```

[image]

Thanks,
Aaban.

Comment: Shoudn't the code be `if !UITextChecker.hasLearnedWord("nooooober")`. Also I believe that UITextChecker only 'learns' the word for the current Document/text. It doesn't add it to the Device's learned words globally.

Answer (score 1):

[Text display and fonts](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts) [UITextChecker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextchecker) works in the context of a single piece of text, like a document.

So any words that you ignore/learn aren't added globally for the device, just the current context that it is being used on. You wont be able to 'learn' words in your app and then expect auto-fill to use them in another app, such as Messages

Comment: Gentleman,  are you sure on it?   that we can't add words globally(Phone autofill dictionary).
Any alternative?

Comment: Do some research, I looked into the class you are using and found that class doesn't do it globally. I am not aware of any others